# Where do you place your validation logic?

Tags: c#, oop

How would you structure your code in the following scenario:

Several business objects (e.g.Person, House, etc), and between them, you need to validate the user inputs (which come in from textboxes). Would that go in either:

1. Each business object
2. The winforms codebehind
3. A seperate (static?) class.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each business object. I have classically made each one implement an IValidator interface that spits out all validation errors for the object.

Answer (score 4):

A very widely used approach, which I endorse in such scenarios, is to introduce the concept of a viewmodel: a class that aggregates all data to be displayed in a form, and which specifies (through attributes or some other mechanism) what type of validation should be performed on this data.

This approach has several benefits which include:

- Decoupling the validation logic from your models (perhaps there are validation scenarios which you want to enforce today but are not inherent in your data itself); this way you are capable of defining distinct validation scenarios for distinct parts of your application where the same business objects come into play (e.g. in some part of the business logic each Person must have a Spouse, but having a Spouse is not an inherent property of every Person everywhere)
- Decoupling the validation from the presentation logic (your view's codebehind); this way you are not forced to specifically tangle your presentation behavior with business object validation
- Validation code being isolated and each part of it targets a specific type of validation only; this way, validation code can be reused across your application wherever it is applicable

The actual code that does the validation will typically be inside a separate validation class; your viewmodel would only dictate how each piece of validation should apply to each piece of data.

Comment: I would recommend against this, the purpose of the ViewModel is to be an adapter for the view so that it can attach to the model. Ie, in WinForms you typically do not have a ViewModel. The ViewModel is, in spite of its name, part of the *view* and not the model. Thus I would avoid putting validation logic there.

Comment: @vidstige: I see in your answer you recommend putting validation code inside the model. How would you handle a form for a Person which must be an adult (based on their birthdate) if there are other forms for Persons where there is no such restriction? You could have a class `Adult : Person`, but then if at some point the business requirements change you have to specifically seek out *this particular use* of `Adult` and change it back to `Person`, which involves modifying lots of type definitions -- but not all of them. Not pretty.

Comment: interesting question! This can indeed easily be handled in a model. Perhaps out of scope for this comment field, but for example this policy can be injected to the ViewModel. This way you have one ViewModel since you have one form and the ViewModel has *two* models.

Answer (score 0):

In the **business objects**. The reason is that you would like your validation rules to be testable. If the rules are important you will want to cover them with tests, if they are not - Don't implement them in the first place. Taking this to the extreme gives you code where the codebehind is extremely thin and does hardly have any logic in them. This is something to desire.

Answer (score 0):

Some good practise here: http://colinjack.blogspot.com/2008/03/domain-model-validation.html

Once in place, in the domain model, the UI should be able to reflect the validation state/output from the model.